# What could trigger the removal of the WiFi device?

Tags: wireless, device-tree

I discovered this morning that `wlan0` on my RPi vanished during the night (at `04:14:13` in the unaltered log below):

```
Dec 18 03:38:46 rpi1 wpa_supplicant[407]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with f0:9f:c2:74:34:fe [GTK=CCMP]
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 dhcpcd[513]: wlan0: carrier lost
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz, 92000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: FR
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 kernel: cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 wpa_supplicant[407]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f0:9f:c2:74:34:fe reason=0 locally_generated=1
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 wpa_supplicant[407]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 wpa_supplicant[407]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=FR
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 dhcpcd[513]: wlan0: deleting default route via 10.100.10.254
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 avahi-daemon[361]: Withdrawing address record for 10.100.10.30 on wlan0.
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 avahi-daemon[361]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 10.100.10.30.
Dec 18 04:14:13 rpi1 avahi-daemon[361]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

This is the first time it is happening and I am wondering what could have triggered this sequence of events?

**EDIT**: I did not realize that I forgot to mention that **a reboot fixed the issue and that the issue is a one-shot (so far at least)**.

Since the logs are explicit about "something happening around the NIC", I am curious about the reason of this drop (more than, say, the weird crash which is not understandable and happens once in a while)

Comment: Now it's working again? Have you had a look at your router? Maybe it has a problem.

Comment: @Ingo: yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that this was fixed by a reboot and it works again. Since this happened out of the blue and there are clear logs about "things that happened around the NIC" I was wondering what could have triggered the drop. I will update the question with this.

Comment: search for `brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier not a ISO3166 code` for perhaps interesting reading

Comment: @JaromandaX: thanks for the lead. It's interesting because I recently updated (a few days before this error) this particular RPi (`dist-upgrade`) and it may have updated some NIC related packages/firmware. I will check that. If the error is triggered by some specific context (such as the temporary loss of an AP for instance) it may be why it happened several days afterwards (and have not happened since)